# Как настроить авторизацию через Яндекс?

Tags: django, oauth2

Я понимаю, вопрос часто возникает, но до чих пор не смог найти ответ на него.
Пытаюсь авторизоваться через Яндекс. Делаю так как указано в документации allauth: URL-адрес обратного вызова: https://oauth.yandex.com/verification_code (делал и так: http: // localhost: 8000 / accounts / yandex / login / callback /)
Выдает ошибку: 40 0 redirect_uri does not match the Callback URL defined for the client В строке браузера: https://oauth.yandex.com/authorize?client_id=a5da4... z В чем может быть причина? P.S. Настроил авторизацию через другие сети (VK, google, OK).

Answer (score 1):

На странице вашего сервиса в яндесе нужно указать тот redirect_uri, который используется  в ссылке
[Документация](https://yandex.com/dev/oauth/doc/dg/reference/auto-code-client.html#auto-code-client__get-code)

Comment: Я пробовал ранее.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю может быть вопрос уже не актуален.
Но в личном кабинете и в переменной в django `SOCIAL_AUTH_YANDEX_OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI надо` прописать `https://yoursite.com/auth/complete/yandex-oauth2/`